# Login into Salesforce community from external website using openid connect

Tags: community, single-sign-on, auth-provider, open-id-connect

I need to create a link/button to login to salesforce community from external web application. My requirement is external web app needs to be the IDP and OpenId connect should be used as provider type. Due to technology preference, I have to use OpenId only, not SAML.

Looking all the similar posts and salesforce documentation, I am able to create a SSO button in community login page (using Auth provider), which takes me to 3rd party application for login and finally allow me to get into salesforce community.

But instead of community login page, I want that button to display inside the external app, so that user logged in to the external app, can directly login into community without navigating to community login page.

I have referred to the following which are really not helping my problem -
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BMZBIA4

Answer (score 0):

1. (if not done) Setup the new Auth Provider of type `Open Id Connect` in Salesforce based of the settings obtained from the external identity provider

Read further on [Configure an Authentication Provider Using OpenID Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_openid_connect.htm&type=5)

See screenshot below; for our use case we used a custom Registration Handler class but you can also opt for auto-generating the class (via option  **Automatically create a registration handler template**)

[image]

2. Under **Experience cloud site** section, Salesforce automatically generates a series of URL based on the name of the auth provider. Communicate the `Callback URL` to the external identity provider, they need to setup this for the correct redirection
3. The custom button in the external app then can redirect to the SSO URL of the auth provider
   `https://your-domain/services/auth/sso/YourAuthProviderName` which will redirect to your Salesforce community home page after processing the SSO for the user connected to the external app

*Side note*:
If you need to redirect to a specific Community Page after the SSO verification, then the custom button URL can include an additional parameter `startURL=/s/your-community-page`

The full URL will be similar to this :
`https://your-domain/services/auth/sso/YourAuthProviderName?startURL=/s/your-community-page`